# Laravel request has with switch statement

Tags: laravel, if-statement, request, switch-statement

I have a form with bunch of submit inputs, each input has a unique name, now I want to check in the controller which input is being clicked.

The Form

```
<input type="submit" name="button_1" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="button_2" value="2">
<input type="submit" name="button_3" value="3">
<!-- and more submit inputs -->
```

in the controller, I use if else now to check which input is being clicked, for example I can use this

```
if ($request->input('button_1'))
    {$message = '1'; // and more code
    }
elseif ($request->input('button_2'))
    {$message = '2'; // and more code
    }
elseif ($request->input('button_3'))
    {$message = '3'; // and more code
    }
// ...
```

or I can use this

```
if ($request->has('button_1')) {$message = '1';}
elseif ($request->has('button_2')) {$message = '2';}
elseif ($request->has('button_3')) {$message = '3';}
// ...
```

is there a better way to check which submit input is being clicked, **like a switch method for example**, because that will make the writing logic much simpler and cleaner but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: `$message = $request->input("button_1") ?? $request->input("button_2") ?? $request->input("button_3");`

Comment: there is a lot of logic after each statement not just a message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can switch on `true`:

```
switch (true) {
  case $request->has('button_1'):
    // do something
    break;
  case $request->has('button_2'):
    // do something else
    break;
  case $request->has('button_3'):
    // do something 
    break;
}
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for. I didn't know that I can switch on true :)

Comment: This was confusing the first time i saw it. A developer used this method in a switch-case  `switch ($transaction->transaction_type_id)` but my confusion is how he used a constant `case Deposit:`, `case Withdrawal:`, `case Transferred:`, `Payment_Received:` to switch between the cases. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 3):

you can set a name to submit buttons and check the sended value from buttons with switch:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <!-- fields -->
    <button type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="1">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="2">Preview</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="2">Advanced edit</button>
</form>
```

```
switch ($request->input('submit_btn')) {
    case '1':
        // do something
        break;
    case '2':
        // do something
        break;
    case '3':
        // do something
        break;
}
```